# Where is .sql file located on Lamp Server using Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: apache2, mysql, lamp

I need to import my `.sql` file from my MySQL database as an attachment and cannot find where it is located.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LAMP with Apache 2.4.7.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Where did you set up the website? (I'm assuming thats what you're doing) Please provide more detail on your problem so that you can get meaningful answers.

Answer (score 0):

you can search for it, you can use the `find` utility:

if you know the full name this would be so easy. Suppose the name is `database.sql` so you can search for it:

```
find / -name database.sql
```

you can get rid of the errors "Permission denied" by redirecting the errors to null.

```
 find / -name database.sql 2>/dev/null
```

Now if you don't know the exact name this would be exhausting for you to determine which is your file, but you can get every .sql file in your system:

```
 find / -name *.sql 2>/dev/null
```